# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" | Doing Dijkstra's algorithm for roads/cities

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, dijkstra, numberformatexception

**I'm trying to read 2 files and store them in an adjacency matrix. However, I'm getting an error of:**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

at project3.Project3.storeData(Project3.java:36)

```
36 | int number = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
```

at project3.Project3.main(Project3.java:64)
which is (in my main method)

```
64 | storeData();
```

My storeData method:

```
public static void storeData() throws IOException {
    digraph = new Digraph();

    File file1 = new File("city.dat");
    Scanner cities = new Scanner(file1);
    File file2 = new File("road.dat");
    Scanner roads = new Scanner(file2);
    while(cities.hasNext()) {
        String delims = "[ ]+";
        String[] tokens = cities.nextLine().split(delims);
        if(tokens.length > 5){
            int number = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            String code = tokens[1];
            String cityName = tokens[2] + " " + tokens[3];
            int pop = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
            int elev = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]);
            digraph.add(new City(number, code, cityName, pop, elev));
        }
        else {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            String code = tokens[1];
            String cityName = tokens[2];
            int pop = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
            int elev = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
            digraph.add(new City(number, code, cityName, pop, elev));
        }
    }
    while(roads.hasNext()) {
        digraph.insertRoad(roads.nextInt() -1, roads.nextInt() -1, roads.nextInt());
    }
    cities.close();
    roads.close();
}
```

I want to figure out why this is happening so I may continue with the rest of my program. Any help would be very appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: you are trying to parse an empty `String` into an `int`, which isn´t possible.

Comment: @Kevin-Esche how would you recommend I go about this? The files I am reading in are for city.dat (Number, 2 Letters, Population, Elevation) and road.dat is (Number, Number, Number)

Comment: String[] tokens = cities.nextLine().split(delims); you are taking an input in this line from console (assumed), is this input null or empty? Or is your delimiter "delims" causing tokens[0] to be empty?

Comment: The exception message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: Just figured out I needed to trim whitespace from the file I was reading...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use nextLine(),try next() and nextInt() instead.